# Is there anyway to send email without fsocket?

Tags: php, email

I have to make "send question mail" system with php and smtp (I'll use Mandrill or Gmail).

But our hosting server prevents us from using fsocket function and we are forced to use smtp.

I cannot find an example of php mail without fsocket.

Is there are anyway to make send mail work without fsocket?

I already bought domain, so It's difficult to change hosting.

Comment: Have you tried using PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) ?

Comment: Cannot use mail too...

Comment: Get your web host to enable these features, or if you're using some sort of limited "free web host", move to a real hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Try using curl with CURLOPT_PORT.